# Trying to copy data from Impala Parquet table to a non-parquet table

Tags: sql, hadoop, impala, parquet

I am moving data around within Impala, not my design, and I have lost some data.  I need to copy the data from the parquet tables back to their original non-parquet tables.  Originally, the developers had done this with a simple one liner in a script.  Since I don't know anything about databases and especially about Impala I was hoping you could help me out.  This is the one line that is used to translate to a parquet table that I need to be reversed.

```
impalaShell -i <ipaddr> use db INVALIDATE METADATA <text_table>; 
CREATE TABLE <parquet_table> LIKE <text_table> STORED AS PARQUET TABLE;
INSERT OVERWRITE <parquet_table> SELECT * FROM <text_table>;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried simply doing `CREATE TABLE <text_table> AS SELECT * FROM <parquet_table>`? Per the [Cloudera documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_create_table.html), this should be possible.. NOTE: Ensure that your `<text_table>` does not exist or use a table name that does not already exist so that you do not accidentally overwrite other data..

Comment: Awesome.  Write it up as the answer and I'll give you points.

Comment: glad it helped. I have also written it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried simply doing

```
 CREATE TABLE <text_table> 
     AS 
 SELECT * 
   FROM <parquet_table>
```

Per the [Cloudera documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_create_table.html), this should be possible.

*NOTE*: Ensure that your  does not exist or use a table name that does not already exist so that you do not accidentally overwrite other data.